# Android : Bottom Menu Bar Hides the Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

in my app i created a bootom menubar layout with floating button and i include that in my main activity and also i place a recycler view in my main activity

i just add 100 items to display in my recyclerview to check whether it was working or not for that when i  run my application the recycler view of last item hides inside the bottom menu bar how to solve this

here is the sample image of what i said

[image]

activity_main.xml

```
 <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        />


 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
        />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        layout="@layout/bottom_menu_bar"
        />
```

bottom menu bar. xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_padding"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_nav"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:elevation="@dimen/floating_b_ele"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: if i add :layout_above="@+id/bottom_nav" then the recyclerview will hide bcoz ConstraintLayout of bottom nav  view top view group height and width was match parent plz check the coading bro

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add a layout_marginBottom to the RecyclerView which is equal to the height of the bottom navigation